# why ami getting this #1305 - FUNCTION homeshopping.partID does not exist

Tags: mysql

mysql php admin table query [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1zkR.png)

I don't see why it says partID is giving me a problem? it is in the table and i think i have them linked correctly. I Have changed a few things i replaced comma with the and statement which cleared up alot of my errors. But since I've done that it continues to give me  #1305 - FUNCTION homeshopping.partID does not exist. I have even looked at the structures an designer to make sure column names an tables are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to post your query as text also.
Because it's missing the keywork *IN* to have a query like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(hscust.first,' ', hscust.last AS Customer,hsitems.description,hsitems.price,hsitems.itemCalss
FROM hscust,hsorders,hslineitem,hsitems
WHERE hslineitems.orderId = hsorders.orderId AND hsitems.partID = hslineitem.partNum AND hslineitem.price = hsitems.price AND partID IN ('CB03', 'CZ82');
```